# getElementsByClassName performance in Google Chrome and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

This code is perfectly running in Google chrome; However, it is not working in Internet Explorer.

```
function HideMyClassItems()
{
    var classone= document.getElementsByClassName('classone');
    for(var i=0; i<classone.length; i++) { 
    classone[i].style.display='none';
    }
}
```

What's wrong?!

Comment: Your page runs in Quirks Mode, that's what's wrong.

Comment: can you explain more, @Tomalak ?

Comment: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/quirksmode.html

Comment: Please check my answer. And comment if it works for you. And at least check the other's answers too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 and under doesn't support `getElementsByClassName()`, but there's three options you can try.

1: You could create a function

```
function getElementsByClassName(node, classname) {
    var a = [];
    var re = new RegExp('(^| )'+classname+'( |$)');
    var els = node.getElementsByTagName("*");
    for(var i=0,j=els.length; i<j; i++)
        if(re.test(els[i].className))a.push(els[i]);
    return a;
}
```

And use the function like this

```
var classone = getElementsByClassName(document.body,'classone');  // no document
```

2: You can use jQuery.

```
var classone = $('.classone');
```

3: You can use the `querySelectorAll()` method/function.

```
var classone = querySelectorAll('.classone');
```

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` method might not be available in all of the browsers.

You can try out `jQuery` library for a cross-browser selector solution.

Answer (score 0):

In case of Internet Explorer, `getElementsByClassName` method is supported since version **9**.

Here's the reference: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname